# DynamoDB Validation Exception - Key element does not match the schema

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to get an item from my DynamoDB but get the following error

> ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the
>   schema

The create item piece of the code works. But no the Get item.

```
Table Info:
Table Name: movieTable
Primary Partition Key: itemID
Primary Sort Key: sortKey
```

Here's the code for the create and update:

```
        var fbUserId;
        var params;
        var keyText;
        var attText;
        var valText;
        var dynamodb = null;
        var docClient = null;
        var appId = '405140756489952'; //from facebook
        var roleArn = 'arn:aws:iam::042765862882:role/Verzosa'; //from AWS IAM
        var resultData = null;

        document.getElementById('putThis').onclick = function () {
            dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({ region: 'us-west-2' });
            docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ service: dynamodb });
            keyText = document.getElementById("keyValue").value;
            attText = document.getElementById("attributeText").value;
            valText = document.getElementById("valueText").value;
            console.log("Key Value: ", keyText);
            console.log("Attribute: ", attText);
            console.log("Value: ", valText);
            params = {
                TableName: 'movieTable',
                Item: {
                    itemID: keyText,
                    sortKey: valText
                }
            };
            docClient.put(params, function(err, data){
                          if (err) console.log(err);
                          else
                          {
                          resultData = data;
                          console.log(resultData);

                          }
                          })


        };

    document.getElementById('getThis').onclick = function () {
        dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({ region: 'us-west-2' });
        docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ service: dynamodb });
        keyText = document.getElementById("keyValue").value;
        attText = document.getElementById("attributeText").value;
        console.log("Key Value: ", keyText);
        console.log("Attribute: ", attText);
        params = {
            TableName: 'movieTable',
            Key: {
                itemID: keyText,
            },
            ProjectionExpression: "#a",
            ExpressionAttributeNames: {
                '#a': attText
            }
        };
        docClient.get(params, function (err, data)
                      {
                      if (err)
                      {
                      console.log(err, err.stack);
                      }
                      else
                      {
                      console.log("success, logging data: ");
                      console.log(data);//shows keys
                      console.log("attribute 1 is " + data.Item.sortKey)
                      //var output = data.Item.attribute1;
                      l = document.getElementById("output");
                      l.innerHTML = data.Item.sortKey;
                      }
                      })
    };
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do all those console.log calls print?

Answer (score 9):

You are getting this error because when using [AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient.get](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#get-property) method, you **must specify both hash and sort key** of an item. But you have only hash key specified (itemId), and sort key is missing.

Here is how your get params should look like:

```
  ...
  params = {
      TableName: 'movieTable',
      Key: {
          itemID: keyText,
          sortKey: valText   // <--- sort key added 
      },
      ProjectionExpression: "#a",
      ExpressionAttributeNames: {
          '#a': attText
      }
  };
  docClient.get(params, function (err, data) {
  ...
```

If you'd like to get a record with a hash key only, without specifying its sort key, you should use [query](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#query-property) method instead of get:

```
  ...
  params = {
      TableName: 'movieTable',
      KeyConditionExpression: '#itemID = :itemID',
      ProjectionExpression: "#a",
      ExpressionAttributeNames: {
          '#a': attText,
          '#itemID': 'itemID'
      },
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
          ':itemID': keyText
      }
  };

  dynamodbDoc.query(params, function(err, data) {
  ...
```

Be aware that while get method always returns 1 or no records, query can possibly return multiple records, so you would have to revisit your current implementation of get callback (e.g. instead of accessing data.Item you should use data.Items array, see [query method docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#query-property))

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass both primary key and sort key in the params.

You can find these keys from the table UI.

[image: screenshot of dynamo db table ui]

and you should pass those as parameters when making the request

```
this.ProjectsModel.delete({pk1:"project#giri-test#appsc", sk1:"metadata#giri-test#appsc"}, (error) => {
            if (error) {
                console.error(error);
            } else {
                console.log("Successfully deleted item");
            }
        });
```